# Maven Android Issue

Tags: java, android, maven, android-bootstrap

I am trying to set up my development environment for Android Bootstrap. I cloned the repo and then executed the maven command: "mvn package clean" but whenever I do get the following error message:

> Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources
>   (default-resources) on project android-bootstrap: Execution default-resources of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources failed: A required class was 
>   missing while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources: org/codehaus/plexus/util/Scanner

I am using maven version 3.1.1, java version 1.7.0_51

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: I was able to fix this by removing the .m2 folder and re-downloading the dependencies. I am not sure why that worked or the what the error message means. So I will still leave this error message open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by removing the .m2 folder and re-downloading the dependencies. I am not sure why that worked or the what the error message means. So I will still leave this error message open.

Answer (score 0):

apache-maven-3.1.1 not suuported now Android. Use apache-maven-3.0.5. It working for me